# How to get the outputs on a single line?

Tags: c

I've got this program that gives me all the right outputs, but I am not able to get them on a single line for some reason. Below shown is a sample execution of the code that the homework wants.

Comment: You can print Boiler Numbers separately outside loop?

Comment: @Rohan Kumar Hi when i print the boiler numbers outside the loop, it only ends up showing me the last value that is 15, and not all the rest. The same happens when I place the print statement in a different function

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
printf("Boiler Numbers [%d,%d]:",start,end);
for (x = start; x <= end; x++)
  {
    output = (x * (x + 1)) / 2;
     printf("%d ", output++);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Last line your printif, change it to this :

```
 printf("Boiler Numbers [%d %d]: %d", start, end, output++);
```

You have a '\n' which is line break command. Replace last line with above and you should be good to go.

Comment: Would not print a space delimited list of numbers.